# Entity Framework 2 way binding to two different DataGridViews

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using Winforms and Entity 5.  I want to enable two way binding so that when the user updates the DataGridView such as a deletion it directly updates the database.

I have this working, but the issue is I have several such grids looking at different sections of the table (The eLECTROSCALES_NO is different).  However using this code I am always getting the copy of the data from the last time this code was run, on all grids.  Essentially is there a way to have multiple Local copies?

```
db.ADCL_ELECTROSETTINGS.Local.Clear();

db.ADCL_ELECTROSETTINGS
    .Where(x => x.ELECTROSCALES_NO == eLECTROSCALES_NO)
    .OrderBy(x => x.DISPORDER)
    .Load();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = db.ADCL_ELECTROSETTINGS.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found was to create a List of context and have one context per dgv.

```
private List<AdclEntities> dbList;

            pageNumber--;  // change from 1 base index to 0 base index;
             AdclEntities tempdb = null;
            if (dbList.Count <= pageNumber || dbList[pageNumber] == null)
            {
                tempdb = new AdclEntities();
                tempdb.SetDatabase();
            }
            else tempdb = dbList[pageNumber];

            tempdb.ADCL_ELECTROSETTINGS
                .Where(x => x.ELECTROSCALES_NO == eLECTROSCALES_NO)
                .OrderBy(x => x.DISPORDER)
                .Load();

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = tempdb.ADCL_ELECTROSETTINGS.Local.ToBindingList();
            dbList.Add(tempdb);
```